# R quantmod data merge regression error

Tags: r, regression, quantmod

This R code throws an error, namely

> Error in .xts(e, .index(e1), .indexCLASS = indexClass(e1),
>   .indexFORMAT = indexFormat(e1),  :    index length must match number
>   of observations

Code:

```
library('quantmod')
library('foreach')


JNK <- getSymbols('JNK', from='2010-01-01',auto.assign=FALSE)[,6]
GSPC <- getSymbols('^GSPC', from='2010-01-01',auto.assign=FALSE)[,6]


JNK <- diff(log(JNK))
GSPC <- diff(log(GSPC))

Data <- na.omit(merge(JNK,GSPC, all=FALSE))
m <- lm(JNK ~ GSPC, data=Data)
plot(m)
```

Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual column names of `Data` are `JNK.Adjusted` and `GSPC.Adjusted`. Hence, you should specify the complete names in the `lm` call:

```
m <- lm(JNK.Adjusted ~ GSPC.Adjusted, data=Data)
plot(m)
```

Otherwise, the `plot` function will look for the columns `JNK` and `GSPC` but will not find them in `Data`.